# Can I shine lamps through a material?

Tags: materials, transparency, lighting, emission

I'm building a warehouse scene and the room has a few sets of windows.  I've applied an image texture to the windows so that it looks like they are dirty, but would still like light to pass through the panes.  I have my lamps set behind the windows and I've turned up transmission and lowered roughness on the windows, but it still doesn't do the trick.  I also tried playing with alpha and using a transparent shader as well as different lamps, but nothing seems to work quite right.  I would like something that looks similar to the attached image.  Would it be better to just use an emission shader on the window panes? I'm using 2.8 and rendering in cycles.  [image: warehousewindows].

Comment: Hello :). Works just fine on my end with *Transmission* set to 1. What exactly doesn't work in your case?

Comment: Have you tried using the image texture as the transparency colour rather than the base colour? It would also help if you showed screenshots of what you ended up with

Comment: setting the image texture to a transparency made a difference.  Thanks!